# Rendered more hooks than previous render - error, suspect react-router-dom and react compatibility

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent React  component, `CreateTopMenuResultPage` which was called when a search button was clicked. Search button opened a new result page and `CreateTopMenuResultPage` was rendered in div id `result-page-sort-menu` in that result page. All components rendered fine

I started getting these errors when I changed my whole solution to use react-router-dom and introduced routing.

Currently , on server, my app, which does not have react-router-dom yet and has the same hooks logic as my local is working fine.

Errors encountering:

`Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`   and

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function..`

Errors point to whereever I am using `useState`

So I am guessing , it might have to do something with 1. mismatching versions of React and React DOM. or 2.more than one copy of React

I get true for this check - `window.React1 === window.React2` as is mentioned in react debug docs [here](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning)

As mentioned in above react doc link , when I run `npm ls react-dom` , I get this tree

```
├─┬ @wordpress/scripts@26.6.0
│ ├─┬ @wordpress/babel-preset-default@7.20.0
│ │ └─┬ @wordpress/element@5.13.0
│ │   └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react-dom@18.2.0
├─┬ rc-slider@10.3.1
│ ├─┬ rc-util@5.38.0
│ │ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.17.0
  └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
```

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

This is the tree from my server where the same hooks logic is working fine

```
├─┬ @wordpress/scripts@26.6.0
│ ├─┬ @wordpress/babel-preset-default@7.20.0
│ │ └─┬ @wordpress/element@5.13.0
│ │   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0
└─┬ rc-slider@10.3.1
  ├─┬ rc-util@5.38.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └── react@18.2.0 deduped
```

Based on that , I guess,  it is not react mismatching or more copies of react that is causing these error . But I may be incorrect
It may have to do something with using `react-router-dom` I am using routing like this

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
   function handleSearch() {
    navigate('/search');

  } 

 return(
    ...  
     <a href="#" className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px"
                         onClick={handleSearch }                       
                          >
                          Search Now
                        </a> 
    ...
    );
```

Is there an issue to use  `useNavigate()` like that

Comment: Can you paste some of the code where `useState` is being called? Make sure you are following [the rules of React Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks): hooks must not be called conditionally.

Comment: I edited above to include `useState` code , where the error for component `CreateTopMenuResultPage` points to and how that useState is used in `RangeSlider` component . I will look at the link you posted

Comment: The excerpt you posted does not appear to have any issues, you did not include enough of the code to diagnose the issue. Paste the entire component where the error appears or check that it's following "the rules of React Hooks" that I posted earlier.

Comment: I checked that link and tried to find , but could not locate anything that was against the rules. Ok , I pasted full `CreateTopMenuResultPage`  component above ( just removed some unnecessary fetching calls and functions) . Content is big though .

Comment: I also tried installing `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` as mentioned in the link you provided and use them with webpack but not seeing any warning or errors in visual studio when I build

Comment: Sorry, I had to stop at your "RenderTopMenuResultPage.js" snippet. Why are you rendering `CreateTopMenuResultPage` into a separate ReactTree? Can you [edit] to get the actual ***un***-minified errors? Or at least include what the error(s) are following the provided links? I think the issue is `CreateTopMenuResultPage` being rendered into its own ReactTree "suddenly", e.g. unexpectedly. Can you include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: There are two top level divs in homepage. When homepage loads `HomePageFlightContainer` renders fine in one of the div. It includes a "Search" button.  When this search button is clicked , react routes to `path="/search"` correctly and loader is shown while data is fetched . This loader is the part `if (!cardLoaded) {` in `CreateTopMenuResultPage` code that I provided above. As soon as data is fetched and `cardLoaded` becomes `true` console throws these errors. All of the error (links) are same `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Comment: I also resolved all `eslint` warnings about wrapping functions in `useCallback` but I still get these `Rendered more hooks..` errors . I will try to include examples but the components are too big. Probably that is why I am unable to figure out. But I was hoping `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` would help . But so far no help from `eslint`

Comment: So as per your comment above , how  should I go about rendering `CreateTopMenuResultPage` in  same tree ?  May be that is the isseue here . I implemented it that way as I did not know any other way

Comment: Think you could try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your app/code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? Please mock any data/API calls/responses.

Comment: My application is too big to be put in codesandbox , mock call and run live.  Can you/anyone please point to any hints based on info above so I can try to debug. I can provide more info if needed

Comment: I edited above to include more focussed code and snippet. If anyone can please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had a vague feeling  that I am doing something wrong when I am using two `ReactDOM.render` in my solution one in `index.js` and other one in `RenderTopMenuResultPage` , the comment made by @Drew Reese ( many thanks!)  in above comments made me to think again and consider an approach where only one react tree should generate as it sounded right in terms of doing things in react.

So now , I changed this

```
export const RenderTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {

    ReactDOM.render(    
        <CreateTopMenuResultPage />, 
        document.getElementById('result-page-sort-menu')
    )
}
```

to

```
export const RenderTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {
    return <CreateTopMenuResultPage />;
};
```

and my index.js is

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRouter /> ,  <HomePageFlightContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('search-flights-container')
   
)
```

Approuter.js is

```
 export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <div >

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePageFlightContainer/>} /> 
                <Route path="/search" element={<RenderTopMenuResultPage />} />
                {/*  <Route path="/" component={<HomePageFlightContainer/> } />*/}
             {/*     <Route path="/wordpress/search" component={<PageFetch />} />*/}


            </Routes>

        </div>
    );
};
```

and also included conditional element where search button is located. This element will render `RenderTopMenuResultPage` , which in turn will render `CreateTopMenuResultPage`

```
   <a href="#" className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px"
                     onClick={handleSearch }  
                      >
                      Search Now
                    </a> 
                    {showResults && (
                      <div id="result-page-sort-menu">
                       
                        <p>This is where search results will be displayed.</p>
                      </div>
                    )}
```

and all errors disappeared

Summary : There was no issue with hooks logic , mismatching versions of React and React DOM , more than one copy of React Or using useNavigate() , the way I am using

Although they may be an issue in some scenarios, in this particular scenario the issue was using two `ReactDOM.render`